# Bookshelf executes strange query when accidentally passing an object instead of a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I have a query that executes totally fine if I send in the right value, which is a did, its ID. But if I for some reason ended up sending in an object by mistake, then it just presumes some value for my ID and returned me a very concerning value.
The query was simple:

```
Did.forge({id:user.did}).fetch()
```

I expected a return of the right values with the identity I sent in. But what happened was that I got returned of a completly other value that expected because I accidently sent in an object. I tested this again and tried to send in this:

```
{did:{test:'asdadad',hoho:'421141144124'}}
```

Instead of this

```
k981t452-2af6-90db-b169-f05b24907801
```

Non of the values in the object adhear to any id of that users returned values.

So my concern is to understand what happens, because if I cant trust the ORM to return no user found when it receives something it should not, it is very difficult to be able to use this framework.
So is there anything i can configure to build better trust?

I have created a gist that explains the usecase: https://gist.github.com/vongohren/e672da6d87143afe82837657df755d7b

There is also an existing issue for this, but its closed, but not solved and explained properly: https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1402

Comment: This seems very strange, and from your description it's not clear what you are doing, what values you are sending, what results you're getting and what results you were expecting. Can you provide a reproducible test case (can be a gist with everything required to just run the code and get back the weird results) and open a new issue on the official [issue tracker](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf)?

Comment: @devius updated now